# jQuery change event only triggering on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a `.js` file that works for the most part, however the change event only is triggering when the page loads, not when the selection changes like it should.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdown").on("change keyup", colorizeSelect()).change();
});

function colorizeSelect(){
    if($("#dropdown").val() == ""){
        $("#dropdown").addClass("dropdown_placeholder");
    }
    else{
        $("#dropdown").removeClass("dropdown_placeholder");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something fundamental that should cause it to trigger when "#dropdown" is changed? `#dropdown` is the ID of a `<select>` object.

Comment: by adding .change(), it's calling itself.

Comment: Amar's correct. I realize now you WANT to call the change function on load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `()` which means execute it now. You are not assigning a reference to it.

```
$("#dropdown").on("change keyup", colorizeSelect()).change();
                                                ^^
                                               ERROR
```

needs to be

```
$("#dropdown").on("change keyup", colorizeSelect).change();
```

Comment: Yup, () is a common mistake. What do you think about the trailing `.change()` on that delegation?

Comment: The .change() is fine, it is just calling it to trigger the event since the defaults are probably not set on the server on load.

Comment: This is interesting. if I do: $("#dropdown").change(function() { colorizeSelect(); }); it requires the (). Any reason why .on is different?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `on`. You can write on the same way. It is because the above assigns a reference to the function and in your comment you have a closure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the culprit here is `colorizeSelect()` , which would execute it then and there. So, the extra parenthesis should be removed.

Hence, change

```
$("#dropdown").on("change keyup", colorizeSelect()).change();
```

to

```
$("#dropdown").on("change keyup", colorizeSelect).change();
```